# IPOPT Insufficient Memory

Tags: scip, ipopt

I'm getting the following error after solving an MINLP problem (GAMS 24.4.1/SCIP version 3.1 (020d055)):

```
Checking feasibility of solution #00 with reported objective value -1.000000970918791e-09.
This is Ipopt version 3.11, running with linear solver ma27.


EXIT: Not enough memory.
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/nlpi/nlpi_ipopt.cpp:1104] ERROR: Ipopt returned with status "Insufficient Memory"
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/nlpi/nlpi.c:503] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/nlp.c:4689] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/nlp.c:5527] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/scip.c:26453] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/heur_subnlp.c:1199] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/heur_subnlp.c:1820] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[reader_gmo.c:2074] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[reader_gmo.c:2371] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[reader_gmo.c:2768] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/dialog.c:828] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/dialog.c:370] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
[../../../ThirdParty/SCIP/scip/src/scip/scip.c:8419] ERROR: Error <-1> in function call
--- Restarting execution
```

I can't retrieve the solution after this happens. Is there a way to avoid this? I can upload the GAMS files if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option gams/resolvenlp = FALSE to avoid this resolve of the sub-NLP at the end.
But it would also be nice to get a hand onto the GAMS model file to have a closer look.